# Guess line integral sign based on a phase portrait

Tags: vector-fields, line-integrals

We have been given the following phase portrait, and asked to guess whether the following lines will result in a positive, zero, or negative line integral when evaluated on the vector field:

1. from (-1,-1) to (1,-1),
2. from (-1,0) to (1,0).

If the line integral represents the work done to drag a particle through the fluid over the given lines, it feels like both should be negative since they go against how the vector field suggests particles should move.
However, I was marked correct for choosing (1) as negative, but wrong for (2) as negative (the correct answer wasn't given to me).

[image]

Clearly I am thinking about this relationship wrong, so how should these questions be considered?

Comment: Your phase portrait is similar to the first example [here](https://gereshes.com/2019/03/04/an-introduction-to-phase-portraits/). It may help.

Comment: Note that along the horizontal line from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ the vector field points strictly in the vertical direction. Work is defined as $\int_\ell \vec F\cdot d\vec s$.